# Get ID url display help

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how to move forward on this. 
How does someone produce this result using PHP and MySQL. 
Original link is `samplesite.com/welecome.php` 
A user then clicks on a link within the page, that link becomes `samplesite.com/welecome.php?hi=54&mov=777`.

I know how to produce the get url id which in this cass is `?hi=54`, how can i accomplish `&mov=77` when someone clicks a link within the page. 
i am using php and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Use at the ?hi=54 page this:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

It shows up the a link with $_GET parameters.

Example:

```
<a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>&mov=77">Next Page</a>
```

Comment: You should `htmlspecialchars()` that query string, for [security reasons](http://codepad.org/ks5lUtVu).

Comment: This will not work well if the user has a long click history. This is not a good way to go.

Comment: It is only "one" way to go. If you want to do it more dynamicly you must conigure the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] anywhere.