# get id url display help, how to call multiple get url id

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to know how to move forward on this. How does someone produce this result using PHP and MySQL. Original link is samplesite.com/welecome.php A user then clicks on a link within the page, that link becomes samplesite.com/welecome.php?hi=54&mov=777.

I know how to produce the get url id which in this cass is ?hi=54, how can i accomplish &mov=77 when someone clicks a link within the page. i am using php and mysql. from one table the contents for id 77 shows up, how can i get the contents for the mov table for id 77 to show up also on the same page.

Comment: Please do not ask identical duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846325/get-id-url-display-help

Answer (score 0):

Im presume that you are using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension for database connection, so your code could look like this:

```
$request = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, array(
    'hi'=> FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'mov'=> FILTER_VALIDATE_INT
));

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie_id=?",$request['mov']);
$sth->execute();
$movie = $sth->fetch();
```